# C++, Qt, Prevent Window from Resizing More than Actual Layout Height

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qscrollarea

Simple question, but I can't seem to get it right.

I have a `QDialog` containing a `QScrollArea`, which contains a `QVBoxLayout`. I want the dialog to be resizable vertically, but only up to the point where the scrollbars disappear, and the layout is shown in full.

I have tried `QDialog::setMaximumHeight(int)` with various parameters, such as size hints, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given description I suggest you to use `QDialog::setMaximumHeight` with `QScrollArea::widget`'s `sizeHint().height()` as an argument like this:

```
setMaximumHeight(widget->sizeHint().height());
```

Take a look at the example I have prepared for you:

https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-MaxDialogHeight

Let me know if you need help adapting it to your particular task.